# How to forcefully Call webview in landscape mode in swift3 ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, orientation

I want my one view controller which is containing webview to come every time in landscape mode. I have written code like this

import UIKit
import WebKit

class DrawWebViewController: UIViewController{

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
```

// var webAView: WKWebView?

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
   // resizeWebView()

}
```

/*  func resizeWebView(){

```
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
    webView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

}*/

    var newUrlVal = "http://wonderhomes.co/draw.php?id=bedroom"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL (string: newUrlVal){
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
        _ = webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    //Image for logo at navigation bar
    let logo = UIImage(named: "logo-250-by-60---1.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
private func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
}
private func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

can anyone please suggest what changes can i make to call webview in landscape mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer -

1. if you want to rotate webview only then use -

myWebView?.transform=CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))

2. if you want view controller in landscape mode -

let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

write the above line where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the below method in `viewDidAppear` method of your ViewController.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

And let all the code remains the same.

Comment: But after that also it is not coming in landscape mode